# Расположением блоков (всплывающий контент или подсказка)

Tags: css, html

При наведении на картинку, блок с подсказкой сдвигает картинку правее себя и нижний ряд картинок.

Хотелось бы, чтоб блок толкал нижний ряд картинок вниз, но при этом НЕ толкал картинку правее себя на ширину подсказки.

P.S. Не знаю чем можно заменить это (ниже) чтоб нижний ряд был под верхним, а не соседствовал справа от 1-го ряда.

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

P.S.2. Не знаю почему, но в разных сервисах для демок ниже представленный код не рабочий, но на ucoz он вполне работает ([клик](http://tm-dwarfs.clan.su/index/exp_page/0-8)). Правда с вышеописанной проблемой.

Код:

```
.items1 {
float: left;
}

.items {
width: 100%;
height:100%;
}

.item {
width: 53px;
height: 53px;
}
.info {
display:none;
width: 400px;
height: 200px;
border-radius:5px;
color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
box-shadow:0px 5px 5px 0px #777;
background-image: radial-gradient(#DFDFDF, #ffffff);
z-index: 2;
}

.item.info:hover  {
display:block;
}

<div class="items1">
<div class="items">
<a class="item" href="http://tmgame.ru/info/artinfo.php?id=147"><img src="http://tmgame.ru/files/art/147.gif?72782"></a>
<div class="info">
подсказка 1.1
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="items1">
<div class="items">
<a class="item" href="http://tmgame.ru/info/artinfo.php?id=147"><img src="http://tmgame.ru/files/art/148.gif?72782"></a>
<div class="info">
подсказка 1.2
</div>
</div>
</div>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>

<div class="items1">
<div class="items">
<a class="item" href="http://tmgame.ru/info/artinfo.php?id=147"><img src="http://tmgame.ru/files/art/149.gif?72782"></a>
<div class="info">
подсказка 2.1
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="items1">
<div class="items">
<a class="item" href="http://tmgame.ru/info/artinfo.php?id=147"><img src="http://tmgame.ru/files/art/152.gif?72782"></a>
<div class="info">
подсказка 2.2
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

в css у `.info` добавьте `position: absolute`
А у `.items` желательно `position:relative`

Должно все работать

Если захотите подсказку расположить справа от блока, то можно будет добавить к `info`

`left:53px`(или ширину картинки)

`top: 25px` (или половину высоты картинки)

Comment: Тогда блок .info пойдет поверх нижнего ряда картинок, т.к. ему задано абсолютное позиционирование. А мне надо чтоб блок .info сдвигал вниз нижестоящий контент (нижний ряд картинок).

Comment: @Алексей это нецелесообразно. Если у вас будет много картинок в несколько рядов и пользователь будет мышкой водить - будет все так нервно дергаться, пользователя будет это раздражать очень сильно. Особенно если подсказка будет по высоте очень большая

Comment: Тогда проще сделать что то в виде спойлеров для картинок?)

Comment: @Алексей Не знаю, что вы называете спойлерами) В зависимости от содержимого подсказки вообще можно было бы взять готовый любой плагин на jquery для тутипов, например `http://qtip2.com/demos` и будет красиво и в любом размере и с любым содержимым в любых направлениях. Кроме раздвижения вниз, конечно